# All hail the Victor

Tags: knowledge, situation

Victor Vauxhall set off in his Vauxhall Victor to drive from Vauxhall to Victoria in London.  He drove at a constant velocity of 30mph.  There was no other traffic on the roads at that time, however he never reached his destination.  Why?

Comment: Is it too early to accept an answer? This is my first puzzle here, so I'm not 100% up on the etiquette

Comment: Phil, you need to wait at minimum 15 minutes from the time the question was asked in order to accept an answer. That said, most people wait a little while to accept an answer in order to increase exposure to their puzzle. However, it is entirely up to you - if you see an answer you like, feel free to accept it! If you want to delay accepting, you could also comment on the individual answers so we have an idea of the sort of answer you were intending on. Welcome to Puzzling.SE, by the way, and thanks for creating this puzzle!

Comment: Accepting an answer indicates the puzzle has been solved, so people stop making new attempts to answer. It's up to you when you do this (some people choose to wait a bit, to get more attention to their question), though note that delaying tends to attract more (and more off-kilter) guesses as the existing guesses are assumed to not have solved the puzzle; if you're going to delay, I'd suggest at least commenting on the right answer so people know.

Comment: @Rubio based on the answer Phil selected, would you and Phil both agree that the Knowledge tag would be more appropriate for this puzzle than the Lateral-Thinking tag?

Comment: I would agree, and am also happy to take advice as the N00b

Comment: @PhilMJones no worries at all! Knowledge works better here because you actually need to know information about the situation at hand in order to solve the problem; a lateral-thinking problem would be more like my first answer below, where the solution requires some out-of-the-box thinking, or is not straightforward.

Comment: Needs a "LITERAL thinking" tag.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'm going to guess that

> Since he was going at a **constant velocity** [which means both constant magnitude **and direction** ] he inevitably crashed into something as he tried to turn (which he can't really do).

Here is a picture of what probably happened

> [image: River Thames]
> Since no one was around to help him, he drowned... :(

Comment: I love this answer. My bloody daily voting limit won't allow me to upvote, so I am favouriting this question $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: I upvoted you before your edit, but now that you've edited it I want to upvote it again. :)

Comment: Rot13 [Pbeerpg - gurer vf na nqqvgvbany unys-pyhr gung abobql unf cvpxrq hc ba lrg gubhtu]

Comment: Is it that r13(ab genssvp ba gur ebnqf, ohg cbffvoyl genssvp va gur jngre)?

Comment: @El-Guest, That's a morbid thought. Watching a car crash into a shipping boat or something like that, no one able to see the smoldering remains of both Victor and the inhabitants of the boat, or hear their screams...

Comment: No, that's not what I had in mind, but I like the idea.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know in a battle between a car and a shipping boat, I'm 73.2% sure that the shipping boat inhabitants will be _just fine_! That said, would you consider this thought more or less morbid than my 3rd guess, above? ;P

Comment: OK, I've decided to go with this one, largely because the picture made me snort coffee on the desk.  But kudos to Rubio for wording it more precisely
The extra half-clue is revealed here - https://bit.ly/2MG2FjP

Comment: I'll edit my answer to make it a little more clear

Comment: Actually, if his velocity was truly constant then he sailed blithely _over_ the River Thames. He probably got into trouble for smashing through buildings, though, and no doubt his velocity stopped being constant after the police apprehended him.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan. Wait, I actually want to set this up as a physics problem now. If we can estimate the weight of the car, and if we know how wide the river is, we may be able to calculate if it is feasible or not. On a note, Victoria would have to be closer to the ground for this to work.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Well, if he's going a constant velocity, why do we assume he stopped in the Thames? Or upon contact with a building? Wouldn't he keep going straight off the edge of the planet and miss Victoria completely?

Comment: @LordFarquaad, Well, 30 mph is a little slow for escape velocity...

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Not if it's constant!

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan That depends on if it's a constant velocity in 3D zero curvature space, or 2D spherical (negative curvature) space.

Comment: Finally got to upvoting. $(+1)$ .... Oh, and by the way, I heard this on the News! After this answer was accepted, the events described in it were definitely deemed true. Police found Victor’s body.... but the car is missing...

Answer (score 15):

Well, since

> [velocity is speed and direction](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/whats-difference-between-speed-velocity-296735), a constant velocity means straight-line motion. That would put Victor in the Thames river.

He will not be reaching Victoria today.

Comment: Actually, reading all answers again, this one is the most accurate, unless this is what Joe-You-Know meant, but didn't quite word it right.

Comment: @PhilMJones I read Joe-You-Know's answer as indicating trying to turn at that speed would be a problem, and intentionally distinguished my answer from that one.

Comment: @Rubio, Actually, I put constant velocity for a reason, knowing that Velocity is both magnitude and direction. Him derailing [in the image] was him hitting something before being dumped in.

Comment: However, I do agree that your answer makes that clearer. And if people want to interpret my answer a different way, your answer is more correct.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I've got a few jokey answers here, and I'm not sure about any of them, which is why this is probably good for a lateral-thinking tag.

Guess 1: (Original guess which is best suited to the lateral-thinking tag)

> His destination wasn't Victoria in London?

---

Other, slightly more jokey guesses:

Guess 2:

> Looking at a map, you have to cross the Thames to get there; maybe he crashed into the river because this is the first obstacle he'd hit if he travelled at a constant speed and direction?

Guess 3:

> The Vauxhall Victor was last produced in 1978, so Victor is dead now?

PS: As a science geek I *really* appreciate Joe-You-Know's answer, because that was my original Guess 2! Go upvote his answer!!

Answer (score 5):

> He ran out of fuel, his car stopped and that's why he never reached Victoria.

Comment: ....how did nobody think of that? $(+1)$ :D